# fx:script shows NullPointerException in scene builder

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I am new with JavaFX FXML and I was trying `fx:script` with this "NMAESTAGE.fxml" file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>
<?language javascript?>

<VBox fx:id="root" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <children>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="83.0" text="Control name:" />
            <Region prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="0.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <TextField />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="228.0">
         <children>
            <Region HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="nextAction()" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="53.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 0; -fx-background-color: rgb(0,110,215);" text="Next" textFill="WHITE">
                <fx:script>
                    function nextAction(){
                        root.getScene().getWindow().hide();
                    }
                </fx:script>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="30.0" left="30.0" right="30.0" top="50.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

**But the problem is**, when I try to open the fxml file in scene builder, the `fx:script` tag is causing a *NullPointerException*. It says that "make sure NAMESTAGE.fxml is a valid fxml file".

**The application compiles, builds, and runs without any error.**
Removing the 5 lines with `fx:script` tag along with the `onAction="nextAction()"` part, somehow solve the problem. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Could anybody help?

Comment: do you change between sencebuilder version ?

Comment: your code is worked for me.Try copy and paste your code again in other file and open it .Maybe you changed version of sceneBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

For me it's a bug, introduced by Scene Builder 2.0; the older versione (1.1) doesn't have the problem